# Current way to disable cache on Chrome using Selenium Webdriver python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, caching

How do you go about disabling cache on Chrome using Selenium Webdriver in python?

I did this but when I check in the browser it does not work

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-application-cache")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: The easiest way to disable browser caching in Google Chrome is simply to use its "Incognito Window" mode

Comment: @4M01 Just tried and the "Disable Cache" option is still not selected though. I did this: chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")

Comment: incognito is not working?

Comment: No it still doesn't automatically select the "Disable Cache" option

Comment: if a browser is working in incognito then you don't have to worry about the cache as it will not store anything anyway, so why go and check Disable cache option. I also checked command line switches for chrome, didn't found any. Have look http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: So even if I refresh the page (not closing the window and reopening), it's a fresh cache everytime?

Comment: or is it better to just close and reopen the window in incognito every time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124088/discussion-between-4m01-and-user3226932).